# Converting from a Html encoded string to a 'normal' Url

Tags: xslt, url, encoding

I have a url in an xml documnent which is encoded

```
<Link>http://www.sample.com/test.asp?goto=HOTWIZ%26eapid=857</Link>
```

I would like to convert that into a Url in the outputed Html.

I can output a link ok but i need the %26 to be converted to an &

I assume i could use some sort of replace functionality in XSLT but I imagine there is a more elegant solution

Cheers

To clarify the intent, is should be two seperate parameters, the url is stored in an xml document so needs the url needs to be encoded

Comment: To clarify the intent, is should be two seperate parameters, the url is stored in an xml document so needs the url needs to be encoded

Answer (score 3):

There is a semantic difference between `…?foo=bar&baz` and `…?foo=bar%26baz`. The first is two arguments (`foo` with the value `bar` and `bar` with an empty value) while the second is just one argument (`foo` with the value `bar&baz`).

Comment: Indeed. If that was supposed to be two parameters, the upstream code that generated it is wrong and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Hi it was supposed to be two parameters

Comment: You'll need to look at the code that spits that out then, you can't really 'fix up' this kind of mangled URL once it has been generated, without losing significant information.

Answer (score 0):

The & has been urlencoded (%26) rather than entity encoded - for a more "pure" xml approach you would entity encode it as `&amp;`

```
<Link>http://www.sample.com/test.asp?goto=HOTWIZ&amp;eapid=857</Link>
```